# jquery tab asp.net staying on tab after postback 0x800a01b6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, tabs

Hello i need to stay on a jquery tab after asp.net postback, but nothing what i found here or somewhere else in the web works for me.

I tried:

[Staying on current jQuery tab across post back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720796/staying-on-current-jquery-tab-across-post-back)

and

[Jquery postback, maintain same tab after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149908/jquery-postback-maintain-same-tab-after-postback)

but also some other sources.

Everytime when im changing

```
  $("#tabs").tabs();
```

to something like:

```
 $(function () {
   $("#tabs").tabs({
       show: function() {
          var selectedTab = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
          $("#<%= hdnSelectedTab.ClientID %>").val(selectedTab);
          },
       selected: <%= hdnSelectedTab.Value %>
   });
 });
```

With hiddenfield etc. i get this error 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'.

When im Using the jquery.cookie.js file with this code:

```
 $("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { expires: 1 } });
```

i dont get an error but i dont stay on the tab after postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your input button a css class.

```
#inputField { 
display:none !important; 
}
```

Save this as yourCssClass.css

```
document.getElementById("inputField ").className += "yourCssClass";
```

Add this to your JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

I found out what the Problem was, I inserted jquery on the end of my master page because of that somehow it overwrote the jqueryui file in that specific aspx file. After i added the jqueryui.js file after the jquery.js everything worked fine.